# How to set javascript variables to json array elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

This is a sample of my Javascript code below. The main reason why I am writing this post is because I have a question about the last function, which is my GalleryImage function. There are four string variables inside that function. In each variable, I am supposed to store an element from the correspoding key in my JSON file's array. How do I do that? Underneath my javascript code is a sample of my JSON file code.

```
function GalleryImage(mJSON) {

    var locate = "";
    var description = "";
    var date = "";
    var url = "";
    //implement me as an object to hold the following data about an image:
    //1. location where photo was taken
    //2. description of photo
    //3. the date when the photo was taken
    //4. either a String (src URL) or an an HTMLImageObject (bitmap of the photo. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)
}
```

---

```
"images": [
        {
            "imgPath": "img/places/australia.jpg",
            "imgLocation": "Australia",
            "description": "Loch Ard Gorge",
            "date": "01/01/2016"
        },
        {
            "imgPath": "img/places/austria.jpg",
            "imgLocation": "Austria",
            "description": "Austrian chapel",
            "date": "01/02/2016"
        }

  ]
}
```

Comment: @Biffen i edited it

Comment: JSON is a notation format. If you do `var images =  [` you will have a JS object. I assume that is what you really mean. Please create a [mcve] to explain the input and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan Starting from that var images code is my JSON file, so it is JSON code. I just need to some how get each key from the images array into the variables inside the Javascript function I wrote. The variables will be strings.

Comment: It is useless as "JSON code" You will get a JS object or you need to use JSON.parse to make the string a JS object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score -1):

You can access the variables from the JS object array like you would do it in a dictionary:

```
element.variable
```

Example:

```
mJson.description
```

I hope my answer was helpful!

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: Does this access the key first though? I know you are accessing the element, but don't we have to access the key first?

Comment: `element.variable` is the same as `element["variable"]`, so you are calling the key when you are calling `element.variable`

Comment: don't we have to parse it into a string or no?

Comment: How did your answer get a dislike, I would assume yours is right.

Comment: No, you don't have to parse it into a string, when you used the general Json parser before. The json parser does anything for you.

Comment: I dont know, why it got a dislike:(

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

```js
debugger;
const images = [
        {
            "imgPath": "img/places/australia.jpg",
            "imgLocation": "Australia",
            "description": "Loch Ard Gorge",
            "date": "01/01/2016"
        },
        {
            "imgPath": "img/places/austria.jpg",
            "imgLocation": "Austria",
            "description": "Austrian chapel",
            "date": "01/02/2016"
        }
];

const GalleryImage = (props) => {
    return {
     locate : props.imgLocation,
     description :  props.description,
     date :  props.date,
     url :  props.imgPath ? props.imgPath : props.imgPath // Here is where you need to check if is a string or use the default bitmap
    };
}

const imagesParsed = images.map(props => GalleryImage(props));
```

Another option is trying to do it with a class but is basically the same concept.